# collapsible output in main panel

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with two related analyses. Within each analysis there are a few distinct types of results.

The interface is getting really busy and I'd like to have the output elements be collapsible ([maybe like this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_simple_in&stacked=h)).

Are there any examples of this type of `ui` file? My current one looks like this:

```
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Analysis 1",
                 sidebarPanel(
                   sliderInput("value1", "some value", 
                               min=1, max=20, value=5, step=0.2)
                 ), 
                 mainPanel(
                   ## these two elements collapse together
                   p(textOutput("results_1_a_text")), 
                   plotOutput("results_1_a_graph", height = "400px"),
                   ## these two elements collapse together
                   p(textOutput("results_1_b_text")), 
                   plotOutput("results_1_b_graph", height = "400px")
                 )
        ), 
        tabPanel("Analysis 2",
                 sidebarPanel(
                   sliderInput("value2", "some value", 
                               min=1, max=20, value=5, step=0.2)
                 ), 
                 mainPanel(
                   ## these two elements collapse together
                   p(textOutput("results_2_a_text")), 
                   plotOutput("results_2_a_graph", height = "400px"),
                   ## these two elements collapse together
                   p(textOutput("results_2_b_text")), 
                   plotOutput("results_2_b_graph", height = "400px")
                 )
        )
      )  
    )
  )
```

Thanks,

Max

Comment: what do you mean by collapsible? it's not clear to me with this example..

Comment: why not use shinydashboard, as it has this feature built in

Comment: Colonel - [the link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse_simple_in&stacked=h) shows an example of collapsing content. I would like to be able to collapse a series of results (e.g. text, plots, etc.) that are generated by the server file.

Comment: pops - I'm looking at that now but it seems like overkill. Plus, I would have to completely rewrite the ui file. I was hoping for something more concise.

Comment: ok have a look at the ShinyBS then http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/changes.html

Comment: ShinyBS completely solves the problem! You should add that as a solution below so that you can get credit.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [ShinyBS](http://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/changes.html). Example taken from there too

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(HTML("This button will open Panel 1 using updateCollapse."),
                     actionButton("p1Button", "Push Me!"),
                     selectInput("styleSelect", "Select style for Panel 1",
                                 c("default", "primary", "danger", "warning", "info", "success"))
        ),
        mainPanel(
          bsCollapse(id = "collapseExample", open = "Panel 2",
                     bsCollapsePanel("Panel 1", "This is a panel with just text ",
                                     "and has the default style. You can change the style in ",
                                     "the sidebar.", style = "info"),
                     bsCollapsePanel("Panel 2", "This panel has a generic plot. ",
                                     "and a 'success' style.", plotOutput("genericPlot"), style = "success")
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$genericPlot <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(100)))
      observeEvent(input$p1Button, ({
        updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", open = "Panel 1")
      }))
      observeEvent(input$styleSelect, ({
        updateCollapse(session, "collapseExample", style = list("Panel 1" = input$styleSelect))
      }))
    }
)
```